# Segmentation fault after mapping a file to memory

Tags: c, file, aes, mmap

I am trying to "mmap" a binary file in order to encrypt it using AES then write the encrypted data to another file(outFile) using the following code. I tried to modify the flags for both functions mmap() and open() but I always get segmentation fault when I run the executable.

```
int main (void)
{
    FILE *outFile; //The output file (encrypted)

    /* A 256 bit key */
    unsigned char *key = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456789012345678901";

    /* A 128 bit IV */
    unsigned char *iv = (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456";

    int fd;
    struct stat sb;
    void * memblock;

    fd = open("result0.jpg",O_RDONLY);

    outFile=fopen("result0enc.jpg","wb");

    fstat(fd, &sb);
    printf("Size: %lu\n", sb.st_size);
    unsigned char decryptedtext[sb.st_size];

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

    /* Initialise the library */
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    OPENSSL_config(NULL);

    memblock = mmap(NULL, sb.st_size,PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (memblock == MAP_FAILED) {
        close(fd);
        perror("Error mmapping the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ciphertext_len = encrypt((unsigned char *)memblock,     sb.st_size,key,iv,ciphertext);
   fwrite( ciphertext,1, sb.st_size,outFile);


    if (munmap(memblock, sb.st_size) == -1) {
        perror("Error un-mmapping the file");
        /* Decide here whether to close(fd) and exit() or not. Depends... */
    }
    close(fd);
    fclose(outFile);

    EVP_cleanup();
    ERR_free_strings();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, You're `iv` will probably be updated during the encryption process, or I should say, it *would* be updated. But you're force-casting a non-const pointer out of read-only const data. When the encryptor attempts to perform that update, it won't end well. Casting rarely fixes *anything*, far more often than not, using it as a "fix" ignores an underlying flaw in the code.

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](http://prohackr112.tk/guide/coding/proper-c-formatting#general). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/guide/coding/proper-c-obfuscation).

Comment: `fd` is opening as read-only, that's the file you're `mmap`ing, then you're attempting to `memcpy` into your `memblock` .. perhaps you have the arguments of `memcpy` in the wrong order? Don't believe you can `memcpy` into a `FILE*` anyway,, try `fwrite` instead.

Comment: iv is only an initialization vector used in the first round by AES, and used only once. I edited the code to replace memcpy by fwrite and still getting segmentation fault, I think the problem comes from the mmap function arguments

Comment: Please add all the necessary includes, there are a lot of them, and in general make it so the code compiles (for example, what is `ciphertext`?) Turn on warnings, usually `-Wall`, and fix all of them ESPECIALLY in cryptographic code. Then see if you're still having a problem.

Comment: you're also not checking return values of any of these system calls, any failures in system calls is also a suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As yano mentioned in the comments, your error is here:

```
 memcpy(outFile, ciphertext, sb.st_size);
```

You're trying to memcpy to a `FILE *` which is completely wrong. That doesn't do at all what you expect. You're overwriting the private internals of the `FILE` structure to which `outFile` points.

You should instead operate on a buffer and use `fwrite` to write to the file.

I suggest you get familiar with basic file I/O operations using `f...` functions before digging into `mmap` and encryption.